# MySQL insert only if a record's timestamp is past 5 minutes

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to accomplish in my query is:

1. Users can store their mobile number in my database, and if the same mobile number is inserted, it will check if 5 minutes had been passed, if it has it will store another record of the same number, if it hasn't then it will not store the record. The column in my database are: Name, contact and date(timestamp)

What I had played around with and written:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, contact) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'test', '123') AS 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT time FROM users WHERE time <= now() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE ) LIMIT 1
```

This will always fail to save the record into the database, since the time is always <= 5 minutes as I'm not matching it to any specific rows. So my question here is: How can I go about matching the 5 minutes interval to a specific mobile number? IE: I want to check if the mobile number '123' had already been in my database for past 5 minutes, if it has then you can use '123' again in the mobile number field.

Comment: Do you mean that it won't allow a  number to be stored within 5 minutes of a duplicate number?

Comment: The same number cannot be stored within these 5 minutes, if these 5 minutes have past, then the same number can be stored once again is what I am trying to achieve. Additonally, if you use a different number, it will be inserted into the database, since there are no existing records of this different number.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following... I used 1 minute because it's quicker to test

```
drop table if exists my_table;

create table my_table
( id serial primary key
, number varchar(12) not null
, dt datetime not null
);

insert into my_table
select null
     , '1111'
     , now()
  from (select 1)x
  left
  join my_table y
    on y.number = '1111'
   and y.dt >= now() - interval 1 minute
 where y.id is null
 limit 1;
```